# tengo una columna varchar en sql server express y se llena de espacios

Tags: visual-studio-2019, sql-server-2022

Estoy con una app web en vs 2019 y sql server express 2022.

Las columnas de texto `varchar(n)` las llena de espacios si es mas corto el texto, el problema es al editar directo en flexview, el usuario al seleccionar uno de los campos lo pone lleno, por ejemplo `varchar(10)` texto insertado `juan`, al editar pone `juan`       (con seis espacios),

Se supone que esto esta bien para la definición `char(n)` pero no para `varchar(n)`